# TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to display a users information on the page but I keep getting an error when I am using this.state.users.map. The same function worked on another page so I don't know why its not working on this page.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import {
  Row,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  Nav,
  Table, 
  NavItem,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu,
  TabContent,
  TabPane
} from "reactstrap";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import classnames from "classnames";
import GalleryProfile from "../../../containers/pages/GalleryProfile";
import Breadcrumb from "../../../containers/navs/Breadcrumb";
import { Colxx } from "../../../components/common/CustomBootstrap";
import IntlMessages from "../../../helpers/IntlMessages";
import SingleLightbox from "../../../components/pages/SingleLightbox";
import { injectIntl } from "react-intl";
import whotoFollowData from "../../../data/follow";
import UserCardBasic from "../../../components/cards/UserCardBasic";
import posts from "../../../data/posts";
import Post from "../../../components/cards/Post";
import Rating from "../../../components/common/Rating";

class EditUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleTab = this.toggleTab.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      activeTab: "1",
      users: [],
    };
    this.friendsData = whotoFollowData.slice();
    this.followData = whotoFollowData.slice(0,5);
  }

  toggleTab(tab) {
    if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
      this.setState({
        activeTab: tab
      });
    }
  }
async componentDidMount() {

    const { userId } = this.props.match.params

try {
    const url = `APIURL/${userId}`
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Token': '1*adminaccesstoken'
        }
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
          console.log(json);
          this.setState({
              users: json
          })
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}
renderUser() {
       return this.state.users.map(function(user, index) {
         const { userId, firstName, lastName } = user //destructuring
     return (
     <div key={user.userId}>  
    <h1>{user.firstName} {user.lastName}</h1>  
</div>
  )
      })
   }

  render() {
     return ( 
      <Fragment>
        <Row>
          <Colxx xxs="12">
         {this.renderUser()}
            <div className="text-zero top-right-button-container">
              <UncontrolledDropdown>
                <DropdownToggle
                  caret
                  color="primary"
                  size="lg"
                  outline
                  className="top-right-button top-right-button-single">
                  <IntlMessages id="pages.actions" />
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                  <DropdownItem header>
                    <IntlMessages id="pages.header" />
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem disabled>
                    <IntlMessages id="pages.delete" />
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    <IntlMessages id="pages.another-action" />
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem divider />
                  <DropdownItem>
                    <IntlMessages id="pages.another-action" />
                  </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </UncontrolledDropdown>
            </div>

<br />
            <Nav tabs className="separator-tabs ml-0 mb-5">
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === "1", "nav-link": true })}
                  onClick={() => { this.toggleTab("1"); }} to="#">
                  <IntlMessages id="pages.profile" />
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                  className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === "2", "nav-link": true })}
                  onClick={() => { this.toggleTab("2"); }}
                  to="#">
                  <IntlMessages id="pages.images" />
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                  className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === "3", "nav-link": true })}
                  onClick={() => { this.toggleTab("3"); }}
                  to="#">
                  <IntlMessages id="pages.friends" />
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
                  <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                  className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === "4", "nav-link": true })}
                  onClick={() => { this.toggleTab("4"); }}
                  to="#">
                  OTHER
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
<br />
<br />
<br />
            <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
              <TabPane tabId="1">
                <Row>
                  <Colxx xxs="12" lg="5" xl="4" className="col-left">
                    <SingleLightbox thumb="/assets/img/profile-pic-l.jpg" large="/assets/img/profile-pic.jpg" className="img-thumbnail card-img social-profile-img" />
                    <Card className="mb-4">
                      <CardBody>
                        <div className="text-center pt-4">
                          <p className="list-item-heading pt-2"></p>
                        </div>
                        <p className="text-muted text-small mb-2"><IntlMessages id="pages.location" /></p>
                        <p className="mb-3"></p>
                        <p className="text-muted text-small mb-2">Email</p>
                        <p className="mb-3"></p>
                        <p className="text-muted text-small mb-2">Phone Number</p>
                        <p className="mb-3"></p>
                        <p className="text-muted text-small mb-2">Date of Birth</p>
                        <p className="mb-3">10/13/1998</p>
                        <p className="text-muted text-small mb-2">VIP?</p>
                        <p className="mb-3"></p>
                         <p className="text-muted text-small mb-2">Points</p>
                        <p className="mb-3"></p>
                      </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                        <Card className="mb-4">
                            <CardBody>
                            <p className="text-muted text-small mb-2">
                          Reviews
                        </p>
                        <div className="mb-3">
                        <p><b>Paris Scottsdale</b></p>
                        <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque quis cursus mauris</p>
                          <Rating total={5} rating={4} interactive={false} />
                        </div>
                           <div className="mb-3">
                        <p><b>Paris Scottsdale</b></p>
                        <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque quis cursus mauris</p>
                          <Rating total={5} rating={1} interactive={false} />
                        </div>
                           <div className="mb-3">
                        <p><b>Paris Scottsdale</b></p>
                        <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque quis cursus mauris</p>
                          <Rating total={5} rating={5} interactive={false} />
                        </div>
                           <div className="mb-3">
                        <p><b>Paris Scottsdale</b></p>
                        <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque quis cursus mauris</p>
                          <Rating total={5} rating={5} interactive={false} />
                        </div>
                          </CardBody>
                          </Card>


                  </Colxx>
                  <Colxx xxs="12" lg="7" xl="8" className="col-right">
                    {
                      posts.map((itemData) => {
                        return <Post data={itemData} key={itemData.key} className="mb-4" />
                      })
                    }
                  </Colxx>
                </Row>
              </TabPane>
              <TabPane tabId="2">
                    <GalleryProfile/>
              </TabPane>
              <TabPane tabId="3">
                <Row>
                  {
                    this.friendsData.map((itemData) => {
                      return (
                        <Colxx xxs="12" md="6" lg="4" key={itemData.key}>
                          <UserCardBasic data={itemData} />
                        </Colxx>
                      )
                    })
                  }
                </Row>
              </TabPane>

                 <TabPane tabId="4">
                     <Colxx xxs="12" lg="12" xl="12" className="col-right">   
                    <Card className="mb-4">
                            <CardBody>
                            <h3 className="text-muted mb-2">
                          Purchases
                        </h3>
                        <div className="mb-3">
                        <p><b>INTL - 10/20/19</b></p>
                          <p>$50.00</p>
                        </div>
                           <div className="mb-3">
                        <p><b>Day N Vegas - 10/20/19</b></p>
                          <p>$500.00</p>
                        </div>
                           <div className="mb-3">
                        <p><b>ClubX VIP - 10/20/19</b></p>
                          <p>$39.99</p>
                        </div>
                           <div className="mb-3">
                        <p><b>INTL - 10/20/19</b></p>
                          <p>$50.00</p>
                        </div>
                          </CardBody>
                          </Card></Colxx>
                               <Colxx xxs="12" lg="12" xl="12" className="col-right">   
                    <Card className="mb-4">
                            <CardBody>
                            <h3 className="text-muted mb-2">
                          Rewards
                        </h3>
            <Table hover>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Check-In ID</th>
                      <th>Club Name</th>
                      <th>Points Gained</th>
                      <th>Points Redeemed</th>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>Promotion Type</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>

                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>INTL</td>
                    <td>+15</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>10/12/19</td>
                    <td>Check-In</td>
                    </tr>
            <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>ClubX Welcome</td>
                    <td>+300</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>10/10/19</td>
                    <td>Welcome Bonus</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>INTL</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>-300</td>
                    <td>10/10/19</td>
                    <td>Free Drink</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </Table>

                          </CardBody>
                          </Card></Colxx>                              
                              <Colxx xxs="12" lg="12" xl="12" className="col-right">   
                    <Card className="mb-4">
                            <CardBody>
                            <h3 className="text-muted mb-2">
                          Promotions
                        </h3>
            <Table hover>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Promotion ID</th>
                      <th>Club Name</th>
                      <th>Promotion Title</th>
                      <th>Date Started</th>
                      <th>Date Ended</th>
                      <th>Promotion Type</th>
                      <th>Redeemed</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>

                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>INTL</td>
                    <td>BOGO On All Bottles</td>
                    <td>10/10/19</td>
                    <td>10/12/19</td>
                    <td>BOGO</td>
                    <td>No</td>
                    </tr>
            <tr>
                      <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>INTL</td>
                    <td>BOGO On All Bottles</td>
                    <td>10/10/19</td>
                    <td>10/12/19</td>
                    <td>BOGO</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>INTL</td>
                    <td>BOGO On All Bottles</td>
                    <td>10/10/19</td>
                    <td>10/12/19</td>
                    <td>BOGO</td>
                    <td>No</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </Table>

                          </CardBody>
                          </Card></Colxx>
<Colxx xxs="12" lg="12" xl="12" className="col-right">
<Card className="mb-4">
                            <CardBody>
                            <h3 className="text-muted mb-2">
                          Reservations
                        </h3>
            <Table hover>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Reservation ID</th>
                      <th>Club Name</th>
                      <th># of People</th>
                      <th>Time Expected</th>
                      <th>Table</th>
                      <th>VIP?</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>

                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>INTL</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>10/19/2019 10:30pm</td>
                    <td>$3,000 Minimum</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td><button className="btn-primary-1" id="editUser" onclick="" >See More</button></td>
                    </tr>
            <tr>
                      <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>INTL</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>10/19/2019 10:30pm</td>
                    <td>$3,000 Minimum</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td><button className="btn-primary-1" id="editUser" onclick="" >See More</button></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </Table>

                          </CardBody>
                          </Card></Colxx>

              </TabPane>

            </TabContent>
          </Colxx>
        </Row>
      </Fragment>
    );
}
}

export default injectIntl(EditUser);
```

I have tried everything that has worked in the past but still no success. My main goal is to be able to display all of the users data on this page.

Comment: Do you have any users? Is this a result of calling map on an empty array?

Comment: @mlunt yes I have users in my api and the user shows up when I console.log it as well and In the tables on other pages.

Comment: I would double check the data type of this.state.users. The map function would work even on an empty array. My guess is the this.state.users variable is getting set to either an object or null and for that reason the map function doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve], emphasis on the _minimal_.

Comment: Please check `this.state.users` should be an array of objects. Means console.log(json); should print an array of objects with proper format and dataType.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of json that you are expecting is not array, please check when renderUser() getting called at first time before componentDidMount gets called.